# How to use quotes in SED commad?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file called "/java.conf", with below line,

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms8250m -Xmx9786m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40"
```

I want to replace the line like below,

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40"
```

I tried the below,

```
JVM_HEAP_SIZE="-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40"

sed -i  "s/-Xms.*/$JVM_HEAP_SIZE/g" /java.conf
```

**Output:**

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40
```

**Problem:** 
Missing a double quote(") at the end of the line.

**Expecting**
If i get a extra " at the end, then the issue is solved.

Basically i am trying to change the "-Xms" and "-Xmx" values, by using a VARIABLE. 
I need to use variable, because the value might change from time to time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please wrap your samples/codes in CODE TAGS a `{}` button in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
JVM_HEAP_SIZE='-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40"'

sed -i "s/-Xms.*/$JVM_HEAP_SIZE/g" /java.conf
```

Text isn't expanded inside single quotes, so the double quote stays intact and replaces the one your `sed` regex matches.

Comment: Hi Aaron, it didnt work. The output is missing " at the end still,

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40

Comment: @Karthikeyan are you sure you didn't make any mistake? It seems to work well for me : https://ideone.com/8L588v

Comment: Yes, it didnt work. Please check the below,

JVM_HEAP_SIZE='-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40"'


sed -i "s/-Xms.*/$JVM_HEAP_SIZE/g"  /java.conf

Output:
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40

Comment: @Karthikeyan Are you sure you checked the correct file? I ask because using a path that starts with a `/` is unusual and I don't see what could fail here. Would `cat /java.conf` output the same thing with the quote missing?

Comment: I tested twice to make sure i didnt do any mistake. when i do cat /java.conf, the (") quote is missing at the end.

Comment: Right the double quote at the end of the string will be treated as part of the script because you're expanding the variable to be part of the script and allowing the shell to interpret the whole thing. Never enclose a whole script in double quotes, use single instead and just open up the script for the minimal section where necessary. So, the correct way to quote that is `sed -i 's/-Xms.*/'"$JVM_HEAP_SIZE"'/' /java.conf` - try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Aaron, sorry, my bad. Its working now. Actually, i use JVM_HEAP_SIZE variable multiple time in a switch case and i didnt update the value on all, that why it didnt work.

Now i declared the below variable in all switch cases, and it worked.
JVM_HEAP_SIZE='-Xms4092m -Xmx4092m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=40"'

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Your sed regex is matching everything from "-Xms" until the end of the line (including the double quote at the end). You just need to put the double quote back as a part of your replacement string:

```
sed -i "s/-Xms.*/${JVM_HEAP_SIZE}\"/" /java.conf
```

Note that, since the search pattern matches the entire line, there's no need to put the 'g' at the end of the command.

Comment: Hi Chris, it didnt work. " is coming, but the value of the variable is not replacing.

JAVA_OPTS="${JVM_HEAP_SIZE}"

Comment: My bad; using single quotes around the sed command causes the `JVM_HEAP_SIZE` variable to not be expanded. You need the double-quotes there after all. Editing my answer accordingly.